# get increment_id from sales_shipment table

Tags: magento2

I want to create a method (in helper) that get **increment_id** value by **order_id** as parameter. So it will look like:

```
public function getIncrementId($orderId)
{    
    $sql = "SELECT increment_id FROM ".$tableName." WHERE order_id = '$orderId'";
    return increment_id;
}
```

In this case maybe `$tableName` will be **sales_order** table. Or maybe there is a resource model that can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
```

Then your function looks like:

```
public function getIncrementId($orderId)
{
    $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT increment_id FROM sales_shipment WHERE order_id = '$orderId'";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        return $item['increment_id'];
    }
    return 0;
}
```